# Latex file on vs code does not autocompile on save

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, pdflatex

I use the extension Latex Workshop, however my preview does not auto update on save. I have to run pdflatex each time.

I tried uninstalling and installing the extension, deleting the extensions file, and even reinstalled vs code. Yet, the same thing persists.

Is there a specific setting, etc that needs to be changed?

Answer (score 16):

Strangely for me it only seems to work when configuring

```json
latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.run: "onSave"
```

Answer (score 5):

As from [here](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Compile#auto-build-latex) the setting for this is:

```
latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.run
```

With value `"onFileChange"`.

Note that this is the default value for this setting, so it should detect the changes automatically, but give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Local and ssh installation:

For me the problem was that I had Latex Workshop installed on SSH but not locally. After installing locally, the LaTEX icon showed up and also auto-compile on save worked right away.